# How to trace MSMQ?

Tags: msmq

I have an agent and a server in different domains. The server acts as an MSMQ server and the agent acts as an MSMQ client. I am using the mqsender utility, which is part of the MSMQ tools.

My problem is that a message is not delivered when using the HTTP:// format string (the MSMQ is installed with HTTP support). Using the OS: format string works fine.

When using HTTP the messages are immediately moved to the Dead Letter queue and the Class is set to Unknown, so I do not know the reasons for this behaviour.

So, this works:

```
mqsender.exe /c:10 /j:dead /f:Direct=OS:il-mark-w2k3\private$\test
```

And this does not:

```
mqsender.exe /c:10 /j:dead /f:Direct=http://il-mark-w2k3/msmq/private$/test
```

I checked that MSMQ virtual directory exists. How can I trace the MSMQ operation to try and understand what is going on?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

1. All the commands work as expected when ran locally on the server.
2. Navigating to `http://il-mark-w2k3/msmq/private$/test` in the browser on the agent (and the server) results in **501 - Header values specify a method that is not implemented**. The same error is received when navigating to `http://il-mark-w2k3/msmq`. I suppose that is OK, after all it is not **404 - Not Found**, right?

**EDIT2**

I have succeeded to resolve the issue. IIS lacked Anonymous Authentication, it became obvious from observing its log - 401.2 HTTP error was there. All worked well after it was enabled. The mistery remains why did MSMQ display Class **Unknown** on the dead messages? On other machine the same setup produces **Error : 401**, which makes much more sense.

Comment: What happens if you browse to http://il-mark-w2k3/msmq/private$/test
in IE?

Comment: Yes, 501 or 5050 is good. Shows the MSMQ MQISE application on the webserver responded to the data you sent.

Comment: Mark, did you forget to accept @JohnBreakwell's answer? Seems he pointed you in the right direction and you wouldn't have solved this without him.

Comment: Well, I have marked it right now. But I do not really know if it helps, because we ditched MSMQ long time ago. Too much friction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logging for MSMQ is internal so you won't easily be able to see exactly why the message didn't get delivered without raising a support case with Microsoft.

I have a few blog posts on [solving various MSMQ/HTTP issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/tags/msmq+over+http/).
The 17 entitled "MSMQ messages using HTTP just won't get delivered" may help.

Also make sure you [check the IIS logs for information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/10/21/troubleshooting-msmq-over-http-nothing-in-the-web-server-log-files.aspx).

Cheers

John Breakwell

Comment: Yea, I have browsed through all of them. In the end what confused me is the Unknown message class of the dead messages - I edited my question to describe the solution.